# How can I get the list of the currently installed certificate authority on my ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, certificate

If I'm correct, the list of CA can be found in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt, but that's only the certificates.

My question is how can I get the name of those CA ? I want to know if the CA my company use is currently in my list of CA or if I need to add it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I don't know for Ubuntu in particular, but some ways of constructing an OpenSSL ca-certificates file leave the subject and/or issuer name (for a root CA these are the same) as a comment immediately before each actual certificate (`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` to `-----END CERTIFICATE----`). If not, or not all (for example certs have been appended after the install):
- You can separate the certificate blocks and run each through `openssl` commandline like this:

  `gawk -vc="openssl x509 -noout -subject" '{print|c}/^-----END/{close(c)}' \
   </etc/ssl/certs/ca-certs # or any other bunch-of-certs file`

Comment: I did not have the CA name in comment, but the second solution did work ! Thank you !